# How to focus to text boxes in bootstrap accordian on validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC5 application, there is a view which containing more than 50 input controls.Therefore I have categorized and organized them in to bootstrap accordion panels. My requirement is : when I fresh the submit button, form should be validated and cursor should be focused to the input field, if there is any validation error. I can achieve this using following code when accordion panels are stay open.

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
 var validator = $("#fromLoanProduct").validate();
 var validationErrorList = validator.errorList;
 });
```

Here I can get the fields with input validation errors from validationErrorList  and focus the cursor on to the first field. However this works when only accordion panels are open.
Can anyone share me a code to open the closed accordion panel when there are fields in side it with input errors?

Comment: How do you open the panel? if with a click event, you can perform a click event like so: `$('#targetID').click();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var validator = $("#fromLoanProduct").validate({ ignore: false });
```

**Related to:** [Jquery validation not working on collapsed bootstrap panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284357/jquery-validation-not-working-on-collapsed-bootstrap-panels)

Comment: I have no voting power. sorry for that